# Unpivot operation in databricks using SQL?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a table called `tbl1` in azure data bricks and I want to perform simple unpivot operation using SQL. I am new to SQL and DataBricks. I followed online tutorial to perform unpivot operation. Based on that I came up with below syntax. But. i am getting this `You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'unpivot( height  for details IN (ucol1, ucol2, ucol3))'` error continuously.

SQL Syntax for unpivot operation.

```
%sql

Select date_format(X.Date,'dd-MMM')Datee
      ,X.width
      ,X.height
      ,X.details
      ,X.col1  
From
(
Select 
Datee,width,B.details,col1,height, from tbl1 A,
Unpivot
(
height 
for details IN (
       ucol1, ucol2, ucol3
)) B
GROUP BY Datee,width,B.Details,height,col1

)X
```

Is there anything wrong with the above SQL syntax?
Any hint would be appreciable.
Please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Extra comma after `height,` also once you unpivot then `height` and `details` are not available to be selected. The error message appears to actually be a MySQL error, which doesn't support `UNPIVOT`?

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for your valuable comment. So, Azure Databricks doesn't support unpivot operation?

Comment: Unpivot is not supported at this time. Have you checked Spark (https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select.html) / Azure Databricks (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select) documentation?

Comment: ... and yet another https://xyproblem.info/. There other ways to achieve what you need other than the currently unsupported Unpivot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stack` in Spark SQL to unpivot, eg

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT( Date, 'dd-MMM') x,
    STACK( 3, ucol1, ucol2, ucol3 )
FROM tbl1;
```

It would be helpful if you provided some simple sample data and expected results as it's not 100% clear what you need as your query does not work in any language.